# Show title in calender PHP

Tags: php, calendar

I have php to display the calender and another php to check database to see bookings, If there is a booking on certain day it displays "Booked". In database i have column for date of booking and title. How could i make it to display Title from the database instead of "Booked"?

This is to display calender.

```
<?php
$monthNames = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May",
"June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
?>

<?php
  if (!isset($_REQUEST["month"]))
   $_REQUEST["month"] = date("n");
  if (!isset($_REQUEST["year"]))
   $_REQUEST["year"] = date("Y");
?>

 <?php
   $cMonth = $_REQUEST["month"];
   $cYear = $_REQUEST["year"];
   $prev_year = $cYear;
   $next_year = $cYear;
   $prev_month = $cMonth-1;
   $next_month = $cMonth+1;
   if ($prev_month == 0 )
  {
        $prev_month = 12;
      $prev_year = $cYear - 1;
  }
  if ($next_month == 13 )
   {
     $next_month = 1;
     $next_year = $cYear + 1;
   }

     require("BookingsDB.php");
     $myBookingsDB = new BookingsDB();
     $bookings = $myBookingsDB->getMonthlyBookings($cMonth,$cYear);
    ?>

 <div align="left">
 <table width="400" border="5" align="left" id="calendar">
 <tr align="center">
 <td bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><table width="100%" border="0"
  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
  <td width="50%" align="left"><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]
 . "?month=". $prev_month . "&year=" . $prev_year; ?>"
 style="color:#FFFFFF">Previous</a></td>
 <td width="50%" align="right"><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]
 . "?month=". $next_month . "&year=" . $next_year; ?>"
 style="color:#FFFFFF">Next</a></td>
 </tr>
 </table></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td align="center"><table width="100%" border="2" cellpadding="2"
 cellspacing="2">
 <tr align="center">
 <td colspan="7" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong> <?php
 echo $monthNames[$cMonth-1].' '.$cYear; ?></strong></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF">
 <strong>S</strong></td>
 <td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF">
 <strong>M</strong></td>
 <td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF">
 <strong>T</strong></td>
 <td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF">
 <strong>W</strong></td>
 <td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF">
 <strong>T</strong></td>
 <td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF">
 <strong>F</strong></td>
 <td align="center" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF">
 <strong>S</strong></td>
 </tr>

 <?php

 require("connection.php");
    $con=mysqli_connect("$mysql_host","$mysql_user","$mysql_password","$mysql_database");

 // Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

 $sql= "select activityEvent.activityTitle from activityEvent";
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

 $timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$cMonth,1,$cYear);
 $maxday = date("t",$timestamp);
 $thismonth = getdate ($timestamp);
 $startday = $thismonth['wday'];
 $today = getdate();


 for ($i=0; $i<($maxday+$startday); $i++)
  {
    if(($i % 7) == 0 )
  {
        echo "<tr> ";
  }

 if($i < $startday)
  {
        echo "<td></td> ";
  }
 else
  {
     $day = $i - $startday + 1;
     $thisDate = new DateTime("$cYear-$cMonth-$day");
     $jsEvent[] = "document.getElementById('trigger" . $i . "').onclick = function() {showForm()};";
     echo "<td align='center' valign='middle' height='20px'><a href='#'  id='trigger" . $i . "'>". ($i - $startday + 1) . "</a>";
     foreach ($bookings as $bookingDate)
    {
        if ($thisDate==$bookingDate)
        {
            echo "Booked";
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
               {

                echo $sql= "select activityEvent.activityTitle from activityEvent";

               }

        }
    }

    echo "</td>";

}
if(($i % 7) == 6 )
{
     echo "</tr> ";
}
}

mysqli_close($con);
 ?>

 <script type="text/javascript">
<?php foreach($jsEvent as $event)
   {
      echo $event;
   } 
 ?>
function showForm(){
  document.getElementById('timeslots').style.display="block";
 };
 </script>
</table></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

This PHP checks booked dates in the database.

```
 <?php
 class BookingsDB
 {
   private $bookings = array();
   private $con;

   public function BookingsDB()
 {
     require("connection.php");
     $this->con = mysqli_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password,$mysql_database);



 }

   public function getMonthlyBookings($thisMonth,$thisYear)
 {
     $sql = "SELECT date,activityTitle FROM activityEvent WHERE YEAR(date) = $thisYear AND MONTH(date) = $thisMonth";
    $result = mysqli_query($this->con,$sql);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
         $thisBooking = $row['date'];
         $thisBookingDateTime = new DateTime($thisBooking);
         array_push($this->bookings,$thisBookingDateTime);
        }
     return $this->bookings;
    }

  public function close()
   {
     mysqli_close($this->con);
   }
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <style>
            .red
            {
                color: red
            }
            .green
            {
                background-color: aquamarine;
            }
            table
            {
                text-align: center;
            }
            td
            {
                height: 60px;
                width: 100px;
            }
            .opcity
            {
                background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
            }
        </style>       
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $Cur_day = date('d');
        $Cur_Month = date('m');
        $Cur_Year = date('Y');
        $op = '';
        if (isset($_REQUEST['month']) || isset($_REQUEST['year']) && isset($_REQUEST['stday']))
        {
            $Mo = $_REQUEST['month'];
            $Year = $_REQUEST['year'];
            $query_date = $Year . '-' . $Mo . '-21';
            if (isset($_REQUEST['opra']))
            {
                $str = $_REQUEST['opra'];
                if ($str == 'iny')
                {
                    $op = '+1 year';
                }
                if ($str == 'dey')
                {
                    $op = '-1 year';
                }
                if ($str == 'inm')
                {
                    $op = '+1 month';
                }
                if ($str == 'dem')
                {
                    $op = '-1 month';
                }
                if ($str == 'dem' || $str == 'inm' || $str == 'dey' || $str == 'iny')
                {
                    $query_date1 = date('Y-m-01', strtotime($op, strtotime($query_date)));
                    $lastDay = date('t', strtotime($op, strtotime($query_date)));
                    $year = date('Y', strtotime($op, strtotime($query_date)));
                    $month = date('n', strtotime($op, strtotime($query_date)));
                    $Month_Name = date('M', strtotime($op, strtotime($query_date)));
                    $pre_month = date('t', strtotime('-1 month', strtotime($year . '-' . $month . '-21')));
                }
                if ($str == 'No')
                {
                    $query_date1 = date('Y-m-01', strtotime($query_date));
                    $lastDay = date('t', strtotime($query_date));
                    $year = date('Y', strtotime($query_date));
                    $month = date('n', strtotime($query_date));
                    $Month_Name = date('M', strtotime($query_date));
                    $pre_month = date('t', strtotime('-1 month', strtotime($year . '-' . $month . '-21')));
                }
            }
            ?> 
            <input type="hidden" name="txt_year" id="txt_year1" value="<?php echo $year; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="txt_month1" id="txt_month1" value="<?php echo $month; ?>">
            <table border="1">    
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="javascript:deyear()" name="deyear"><<</a></td>
                    <td><a href="javascript:demonth()"><</a></td>
                    <td colspan="3"><?php echo $Month_Name . "-" . $year; ?></td>
                    <td><a href="javascript:incmonth()">></a></td>
                    <td><a href="javascript:incyear()">>></a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <?php
                    echo '<tr>';
                    for ($i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++)
                    {
                        if ($_REQUEST['stday'] == 'Sun')
                        {
                            $j_val = 0;
                            echo "<th>" . date("l", gmmktime(0, 0, 0, 11, $i, 2015));
                            echo '</th>';
                        } else
                        {
                            $j_val = 1;
                            echo "<th>" . date("l", gmmktime(0, 0, 0, 6, $i, 2015));
                            echo '</th>';
                        }
                    }
                    echo '</tr>';
                    ?>
                </tr>
                <?php
                $Conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "demo");
                $firstDays = mktime(0, 0, 0, date($month), 1, date($year));
                $weekday = date('N', $firstDays);
                $i = 0;
                $j = 0;
                $date = 1;
                $Count = 0;
                $Count1 = 0;
                $next_mo = 1;

                function Holiday($day1, $month1, $year1)
                {
                    global $Conn;
                    $result = $Conn->query("SELECT * FROM holiday");
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                    {
                        if ($row['day'] == $day1 && $row['month'] == $month1 && $row['year'] == $year1)
                        {
                            return $row['title'] . "<br>";
                        }
                    }
                }
                for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++)
                {
                    echo '<tr>';
                    $pre_month = $pre_month - ($weekday - $j_val);
                    for ($j = $j_val; $j <= 6 + $j_val; $j++)
                    {
                        if ($Count < $weekday - $j_val && ($weekday != 7 || $_REQUEST['stday'] == 'Mon'))
                        {
                            echo "<td class='opcity'>" . ( ++$pre_month) . "</td>";
                            $Count++;
                        } else
                        {
                            if ($date <= $lastDay)
                            {
                                if ($Cur_day == $date && $Cur_Month == $month && $Cur_Year == $year)
                                {
                                    if (date("l", gmmktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $date, $year)) == 'Sunday')
                                    {
                                        echo '<td class = "green red">';
                                        echo Holiday($date, $month, $year);
                                    } else
                                    {
                                        echo '<td class = "green">';
                                        echo Holiday($date, $month, $year);
                                    }
                                } else
                                {
                                    if (date("l", gmmktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $date, $year)) == 'Sunday')
                                    {
                                        echo '<td class = "red">';
                                        echo Holiday($date, $month, $year);
                                    } else
                                    {
                                        echo '<td >';
                                        echo Holiday($date, $month, $year);
                                    }
                                }
                                echo $date;
                                echo '</td>';
                                $date++;
                                if ($date == $lastDay)
                                {
                                    $i = 7;
                                }
                            } else
                            {
                                echo "<td class='opcity'>" . $next_mo++ . "</td>";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
            }
            ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
//<Ajax_cal.php

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script src="JS/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            function Caleonload()
            {
                $('#month').val('<?php echo date("n"); ?>');
                $('#year').val('<?php echo date('Y'); ?>');
                Opretion('No');
            }
            function Cal(month)
            {
                $('#month').val(month);
                Opretion('No');
            }
            function Cal1(year)
            {
                $('#year').val(year);
                Opretion('No');
            }
            function Opretion(Op)
            {
                var st_day = $('input[type="radio"][class="rd_sun_mon"]:checked').val();
                var Mo = $('#month').val();
                var Year = $('#year').val();
                var Op1 = Op;
                $.post("AJAX/Ajax_Cal.php",
                        {
                            month: Mo,
                            year: Year,
                            opra: Op1,
                            stday: st_day
                        },
                function (data)
                {
                    $('#Show_Cal').html(data);
                    var txt_year = $('#txt_year1').val();
                    $("#year").html('');
                    for (var y = parseInt(txt_year) - 5; y < parseInt(txt_year) + 5; y++)
                    {
                        $("#year").append('<option value="' + y + '">' + y + '</option>');
                    }
                    $('#year').val(txt_year);
                    $('#month').val($('#txt_month1').val());
                }
                );
            }
            function incyear()
            {
                Opretion('iny');
            }
            function deyear()
            {
                Opretion('dey');
            }
            function incmonth()
            {
                Opretion('inm');
            }
            function demonth()
            {
                Opretion('dem');
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="Caleonload()">       
        <select name="month" id="month" onchange="Cal(this.value)" size="1">            
            <option value="1">January</option>
            <option value="2">February</option>
            <option value="3">March</option>
            <option value="4">April</option>
            <option value="5">May</option>
            <option value="6">June</option>
            <option value="7">July</option>
            <option value="8">August</option>
            <option value="9">September</option>
            <option value="10">October</option>
            <option value="11">November</option>
            <option value="12">December</option>
        </select>    
        <select name="year" id="year" onchange="Cal1(this.value)" size="1">
            <option value="2013">2013</option>
            <option value="2014">2014</option>
            <option value="2015">2015</option>
            <option value="2016">2016</option>
        </select>    
        Starting Day :
        <input type="radio" name="rd_sun_mon" class="rd_sun_mon" value="Sun" checked="" onchange="Opretion('No')">Sunday
        <input type="radio" name="rd_sun_mon" class="rd_sun_mon" value="Mon" onchange="Opretion('No')">Monday
        <div id="Show_Cal"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

DATA BASE PHP MY ADDMIN:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `holiday` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `day` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `month` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `year` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that is that you need to put the format in order to compare two Datetime :

```
if ($thisDate->format('Y-m-d')==$bookingDate->format('Y-m-d'))
    {
        echo "Booked";
        ....
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @SimonGuichard's answer, I suggest that you return an associative array from the `getMonthlyBookings` function that contains both the `date` and the `activityTitle`. This way, you wouldn't have to select the title from the database again when it needs to be displayed.

```
public function getMonthlyBookings($thisMonth,$thisYear) {
    $sql = "SELECT date,activityTitle FROM activityEvent WHERE YEAR(date) = $thisYear AND MONTH(date) = $thisMonth";
    $result = mysqli_query($this->con,$sql);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $this->bookings[] = array('date'=>new DateTime($row['date']), 'activityTitle'=>$row['activityTitle']);
    }
    return $this->bookings;
}
```

Then in the script that displays the calendar, you should modify it this way:

```
$day = $i - $startday + 1;
$thisDate = new DateTime("$cYear-$cMonth-$day");
$jsEvent[] = "document.getElementById('trigger" . $i . "').onclick = function() {showForm()};";
echo "<td align='center' valign='middle' height='20px'><a href='#'  id='trigger" . $i . "'>". ($i - $startday + 1) . "</a>";

// $bookings is an associative array of the form array('0'=>array('date'=>'date_value', 'activityTitle'=>'activityTitle_value'))
foreach ($bookings as $key => $value) {

    if ($thisDate->format('Y-m-d') === $value['date']->format('Y-m-d')) {
        // this prints out the activity title
        echo $value['activityTitle'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, just you have two $$ for if statement which gave me error at the start.